# haproxy redirect www sites and not http sites

Tags: haproxy

I am trying to do some redirections with haproxy. I have 2 sites www.example.com and http://example.com

I want to redirect www.example.com to www2.example.com

But http://example.com should not be redirected, as it is being referenced by page.

How to do this with haproxy ?

Regards,

K

Answer (score 1):

**Redirect based on Host header in HAProxy**

If your goal is to redirect www.example.com to www2.example.com, then below is one way.  302 is temporary redirect, 301 is perm.

```
redirect prefix http://www2.example.com code 302 if { hdr(host) -i www.example.com }
```

Assuming you want to leave the apex (bare / naked) domain alone, the above should work.